# three.js action on click(requestAnimationFrame)

Tags: javascript, three.js, requestanimationframe

I want the camera to rotate constantly when the button is clicked + =
And it turns out that there is a trigger for 2 seconds (on click) and ends.

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn--left');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
     camera.position.x+=(3*Math.sin(angle/6));
     camera.position.z+=(3*Math.cos(angle/6));
});

let angle = 0;

const animate = function () {
     requestAnimationFrame( animate );
     angle-=Math.PI/180*2;

     renderer.render( scene, camera );
     controls.update();
     camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
};

animate();
```

Comment: Can you clarify the first paragraph? Especially the _"when the button is clicked + = And it turns out that there is a trigger for 2 seconds (on click) and ends"_. What do you want exactly?

Comment: I want a parameter, for example x, to get into requestanimationframe when clicked, and become not just 5 but + = 5

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want this: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/QWEpvLg?editors=1010

[image]

Basically, there is a `shouldRotate` variable that indicates when the camera should rotate. By default it is `false`.

Inside `animate` we check if `shouldRotate === true`, if this holds true then the rotation happens.

```
if (shouldRotate) {
  angle -= Math.PI/180*2;
  camera.position.x+=(3*Math.sin(angle/6));
  camera.position.z+=(3*Math.cos(angle/6));
}
```

When the button is clicked a `setTimeout` of 2 seconds is set. When the timer is over it will make `shouldRotate = false`. Like this:

```
btn.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
  shouldRotate = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    shouldRotate = false;
  }, 2000)
});
```